# Find all CSV records that contain a field with a certain value

Tags: perl, csv

I am a beginner in Perl and I need your help.

I have a file containing results from processing other files that I would like to analyse. My file contains the following results:

```
default,primary,secondary,copy_directory,forced_copy_flag,always_allow_dump,type_of_dump,full_memory_dump,

d100spuptl25e0,/dev/lg_dumplv,/dev/sysdumpnull,/var/adm/ras,1,1,fault,disallow,
doc1,/del,/dev/null,/ras,1,0,fw-assisted,disallow,
doc2,/dev/lg_dumplv,/dev/sysdumpnull,//ras,1,1,fw,disallow,
doc3,/dev/lg_dumplv,/dev/sysdumpnull,/var/adm/ras,1,fault,fw-assisted,disallow,
doc4,5,fault,7,8,9,10,disallow,
```

The first field on each line is the name of the file; the first `default` file should be ignored: only the other files must be treated.

I would like the names of the files where one of the values is `fault`, as well as a count of such files.

In the present case here the result would be:

```
number of files: 3
File names are:
d100spuptl25e0
doc3
doc4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is important that you try to solve the problem yourself, and I really shouldn't be offering this without insisting that you make at least *some* effort. But I tire of constantly pressing the point and today it is easier just to craft a solution. Just don't expect to get away with it another time!

This will do as you ask

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use List::Util 'any';

open my $fh, '<', 'myfile.txt' or die $!;

my @files;

while ( <$fh> ) {
  next unless /\S/;
  chomp;
  my ($file, @fields) = split /,/;
  next if $file eq 'default';
  push @files, $file if any { $_ eq 'fault' } @fields;
}

printf "number of files: %d\n", scalar @files;
print "File names are:\n";
print "$_\n" for @files;
```

**output**

```
number of files: 3
File names are:
d100spuptl25e0
doc3
doc4
```

Comment: @Henri - You should accept the answer if it helped you out! Marking it as accepted indicates to future users having the same problem, that this is a valid solution. Besides that, you will earn a new shiny Scholar badge :)